# Variable Expansion in Cobbler kopts

Tags: provisioning, cobbler

In my environment I have large numbers of systems with two interfaces, one is used for system access and management and the other is used for network monitoring. They both are in a link-up state but the monitoring port is TX blocked.

When using koan to reprovision these hosts against cobbler anaconda is inconsistent with which interface it names eth0, and since they both have link, I'm resorting to using `ksdevice=<MAC>`.

Ideally, I would like to use the built in cobbler variables to do this on the global level, so adding `ksdevice=$interfaces['eth0']['mac_address']` to my kopts variable. However, cobbler doesn't seem to expand variables at this level.

Is there a way, built into cobbler, to populate system variables into the kopts field?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, yes. Take a look at [this Trac ticket](https://fedorahosted.org/cobbler/ticket/21) on how to "allow templating variables to be used in `--kopts`".

With regards to `koan`, the comments in the same ticket are informative. Relevant part reproduced here for completeness:

> This is implemented with `@@variablename@@` for anything that runs through the templating engine (`kickstart` + `PXE` stuff). `koan`'s aware [...] because it pulls down `kickstart` files.

Comment: Either I'm messing something up really badly or it doesn't actually work as claimed. This updates the PXE boot entries but not the boot entry generated with koan.